# How to create a matrix with moving elements?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create a code for an 8x8 matrix that is full of zeros except[1,1] and [8,8]. These values would be equal to 1. I then want to make the 1's at each corner be able to move up, down, left, right, as long as it is within the matrix. I would like to be able to find out how many moves until the 1's cross each other.

I understand I need to make 2 arrays but really unsure how to code this.

Comment: If you can _describe_ it, you can start coding it: what code have you come up with so far?

Comment: [bfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) is good point to start

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for loop to create the matrix like this:

```
matrix = []

for x in range(8):
    matrix.append([])
    for y in range(8):
        matrix[x].append(0)
```

Then you can change matrix[1][1], and matrix[8][8] to 1's.
However, I'm pretty sure you meant matrix[0][0] and matrix[7][7] because list indexing starts at [0].

```
matrix[0][0] = 1
matrix[7][7] = 1
```

To move the 1's across the matrix, you can create a function called move() and then remember the positions of the 1's in variables

```
posX = [0, 7]
posY = [0, 7]

#argument dirn, 0 = right, 1 = left, 2 = up, 3 = down
#argument one, gives which one you want to move

def move(dirn, one):
   if dirn == 0 and posX[one] < 7:
      matrix[posX[one]][posY[one]] = 0
      matrix[posX[one] + 1][posY[one]] = 1
      posX[one] = posX[one] + 1

   if dirn == 1 and posX[one] > 0:
      matrix[posX[one]][posY[one]] = 0
      matrix[posX[one] - 1][posY[one]] = 1
      posX[one] = posX[one] - 1

   if dirn == 2 and posY[one] < 7:
      matrix[posX[one]][posY[one]] = 0
      matrix[posX[one]][posY[one] + 1] = 1
      posY[one] = posY[one] + 1

   if dirn == 3 and posY[one] > 0:
      matrix[posX[one]][posY[one]] = 0
      matrix[posX[one]][posY[one] - 1] = 1
      posY[one] = posY[one] - 1
```

You can find out how many moves until the 1's cross each other, by adding 1 to a variable every time you make a move. Then check if the ones are crossing each other.

```
moves = 0
while not [posX[0], posY[0]] == [posX[1], posY[1]]:
   #make a move
   moves += 1
```

Total moves made will be the moves variable after the process has ended. Print the value of the moves variable after the while loop.

```
print(moves)
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for this... i've been trying to run it and havent been able to execute it due to the while loop; trying to see how to speed up the process

Comment: What problem is the while loop causing? Usually the problem is that it never ends. To prevent slowing when using bad moves (moves that never lead to the ones crossing each other), add a move limit , say 1000 , so that the while loop will automatically terminate when bad moves are given.

Comment: I see! How is the move() function used within this?